# Is it safe to use es2017 lib in an Ionic 3 application?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

Though [Ionic 4 beta](https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/) is still coming, it'll use es2017 lib at `tsconfig.json`, as we can see it [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/angular/tsconfig.json) on angular dir and [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/core/tsconfig.json) at core dir.

The latest version of Ionic 3 otherwise, ended up with es2015 lib on [tsconfig.json](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/v3/tsconfig.json).

Is it safe to switch lib for es2017 on an Ionic 3 application?

I know [Angular](https://angular.io/) had some troubles with es2017 in the past but it'll be good to use features like [Array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/contains) etc.

Comment: how are you going to import a 3rd party library or are you asking is it just safe to switch config to es2017?

Comment: Just asking. I'm currently not using any 3rd party library that relies on es2017 but it's just boring to use old es code. I think it may break something anytime, otherwise, ionic 3 contributors would have done it earlier.

Comment: Got it, I am just not sure of the motivation behind the question. If you basically are saying "Hey I want to use features of ES2017 such as async/await and unsure if I can" that would be more straight forward;)

Comment: Got it. It's exactly that, but not specifically just `async` / `await`, right now it's mainly because of `Array.includes`. But, as I said, I'm just want to be sure that any es2017 will not break my application or not be supported / transpiled anyhow.

Comment: ES2017 brings e.g. `String.prototype.padStart` und ...`padEnd`. Which is a nice string manipulation. I don't yet know what's required to use this. I think maybe you have to add some polyfills to support older browsers. But e.g. if you running on latest Android devices - which uses chrome webview, you'll have no problems.